# Ambiguous column name, joining three tables

Tags: sqlite, join

I am using "DB Browser for SQLite" to test my SQL query and I get the error:

> ambiguous column name: Devices.Label

I have a database with three tables:
[image: Devices]
[image: Humidity]
[image: Temperature]

I want to get a result with the latest timestamp from each device, so something like:

```
Hot  | 1545074701 | 25.8  
Hot  | 1545071101 | 23.2  
Cool | 1545071101 | 24.0
```

My query looks like:

```
SELECT Devices.Label, max(Humidity.Timestamp), Humidity.H, max(Temperature.Timestamp), Temperature.C
FROM Temperature, Humidity
INNER JOIN Devices ON Temperature.DeviceID = Devices.DeviceID
INNER JOIN Devices ON Humidity.DeviceID = Devices.DeviceID;
```

What am I missing? Have I not specified from which table I am taking the info?
And the next step would of course be to get the proper result from the query, this will then be sent as a JSON object to an Android application.

Comment: You have two `Devices` in the query. Now the parser doesn't know which one you mean in `Devices.Label`. Alias the `Devices` in the `FROM` clause and qualify all references to its columns with the respective alias.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sticky bit I changed my query to:

```
SELECT 
    DevHum.Label, MAX(Humidity.Timestamp), Humidity.H, Temperature.C
FROM 
    Temperature, Humidity
INNER JOIN 
    Devices AS DevTemp ON Temperature.DeviceID = DevTemp.DeviceID
INNER JOIN 
    Devices AS DevHum ON Humidity.DeviceID = DevHum.DeviceID;`
```

Which seem to do the trick.

I decided to split it up in two queries, one for Hot and one for cool as combining them is above my level right now.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged